# MATLAB - Need to split a Matrix into column variables with names sourced from another matrix?

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab and I am having some trouble.

I have two matrices that I obtained via importing data these are 'label' (a cell matrix of text) and 'data' (a matrix of doubles?). I need to be able to create variables relating to each column to allow them to be individually plotted and used in calculations. These variables should be automatically named using text from the label matrix. I can't use textread as these matices vary in size depending on source data

Below is an example of my issue

Data =

```
    1  2  3  4

    5  6  7  8

    9 10 11 12
```

label = A B C D

I require some code to make Matlab automatically create variables as follows

A =
 1

5

9

B =

2

6

10

etc.

I tried using 'eval' to evaluate my label matrix and then '=' to assign the column, but I get an error message because my data matrix is a 'doubles' matrix not a 'cell' matrix.

Thanks for any help you can offer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [dynamic field names](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/):

```
Data= [1 2 3 4;
       5 6 7 8; 
       9 10 11 12];
Label={'A','B','C','D'};

for iter=1:length(Label)
    DataStruct.(Label{iter})=Data(:,iter);
                ___________<--- field name created automatically
end

>> DataStruct

DataStruct = 

    A: [3x1 double]
    B: [3x1 double]
    C: [3x1 double]
    D: [3x1 double]

>> DataStruct.A

ans =

     1
     5
     9
```

This approach has the advantage that it keeps together(in a conceptual unit) all the data that came from the spreadsheet or other source, and won't accidentally overwrite variables in your workspace if the name of a column happens to already exist as a variable (or even worse, potentially, a function... )

Answer (score 0):

I do agree that its a tricky task....Here is the solution

```
    Data=[1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12]; % A matrix
label=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']; % its a cell array
for i=1:numel(label)
    v=genvarname(label(i)); %  Generating the variable names
    eval([v ' = Data(i,:)']); % Assinging values into named variables 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hasan's code works well but "label" has to be a cell array and not a vector so you have to write label={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'} and label{i}. If you want 4 columns write Data(:,i).

```
Data=[1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12]; % A matrix
label={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}; % its a cell array
for i=1:numel(label)
    v=genvarname(label{i}); %  Generating the variable names
    eval([v ' = Data(:,i)']); % Assinging values into named variables 
end
```